# Reduce complex javascript array to another array based on some calculation?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects

```
data: [
    {
        eventId: "EVEN00001",
        eventType: "call",
        startDate: "2018-08-01T21:30:17+05:30",
    },
    {
        eventId: "EVEN00002",
        eventType: "call",
        startDate: "2018-08-01T21:30:17+05:30",
    },
    {
        eventId: "EVEN00003",
        eventType: "meeting",
        startDate: "2017-02-03T21:30:17+05:30",
    },
    {
        eventId: "EVEN00004",
        eventType: "email",
        startDate: "2018-09-04T21:30:17+05:30",
    },
    {
        eventId: "EVEN00005",
        eventType: "meeting",
        startDate: "2018-09-05T21:30:17+05:30",
    }]
```

I want to reduce it to

```
[{call: 2},{meeting: 2},{email: 1}]
```

how can I achieve this using javascript reduce method ,
somehow, I am able to achieve the desired result but it is not the right approach.

```
data.reduce((acc, item, i, arr) => {
        if (!acc[item.startDate]) {
            acc[item.startDate] = 1;
        } else {
            acc[item.startDate] += 1;
        }
        return acc;
    }, {});
const dayArray = Object.entries(trimedData)
    .reduce((acc, node, i, arr) => {

        let [days, val] = node;
        acc.push({
            days: days,
            value: val
        })
        return acc;
    }, []);
```

how can I achieve the desired result by only using reduce.or any other better approach?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, actually there are two meetings, I have edited the question

Comment: your code, by the way, does not `achieve the desired result` at all - not even close ... it is an array of objects with dates and a count

Comment: I have a long array with different startDates and  I want to show charts for 
events count for  weekly, monthly and yearly .so before counting the email., calls and meetings i have filtered it by the viewType(call, meeting ...),

Answer (score 3):

`reduce` into an object indexed by the `eventType` whose values are the number of occurences of that `eventType` so far - increment the appropriate property by one on every iteration. Then, get that object's values:

```js
const data=[{eventId:"EVEN00001",eventType:"call",startDate:"2018-08-01T21:30:17+05:30",},{eventId:"EVEN00002",eventType:"call",startDate:"2018-08-01T21:30:17+05:30",},{eventId:"EVEN00003",eventType:"meeting",startDate:"2017-02-03T21:30:17+05:30",},{eventId:"EVEN00004",eventType:"email",startDate:"2018-09-04T21:30:17+05:30",},{eventId:"EVEN00005",eventType:"meeting",startDate:"2018-09-05T21:30:17+05:30",}]

console.log(Object.values(
  data.reduce((a, { eventType }) => {
    if (!a[eventType]) a[eventType] = { [eventType] : 0 };
    a[eventType][eventType]++;
    return a;
  }, {})
));
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why your reduce is using `startDate` and not `eventType`

Other than that, you seemed to be on the right track

```js
let data = [{
    eventId: "EVEN00001",
    eventType: "call",
    startDate: "2018-08-01T21:30:17+05:30",
  },
  {
    eventId: "EVEN00002",
    eventType: "call",
    startDate: "2018-08-01T21:30:17+05:30",
  },
  {
    eventId: "EVEN00003",
    eventType: "meeting",
    startDate: "2017-02-03T21:30:17+05:30",
  },
  {
    eventId: "EVEN00004",
    eventType: "email",
    startDate: "2018-09-04T21:30:17+05:30",
  },
  {
    eventId: "EVEN00005",
    eventType: "meeting",
    startDate: "2018-09-05T21:30:17+05:30",
  }
];
let result = Object.entries(data.reduce((acc, {eventType}) => (acc[eventType] = (acc[eventType] || 0) + 1, acc), {})).map(([k, v]) => ({[k]:v}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, actually there are two meetings, I have edited the question

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce them pretty easily to an object, if you then really want the array, just map the object's entries

```js
const res = data.reduce((a, b) => {
  a[b.eventType] = (a[b.eventType] || 0) + 1;
  return a;
}, {});

const arr = Object.entries(res).map(([k, v]) => ({
  [k]: v
}));
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script>
  const data = [{
      eventId: "EVEN00001",
      eventType: "call",
      startDate: "2018-08-01T21:30:17+05:30",
    },
    {
      eventId: "EVEN00002",
      eventType: "call",
      startDate: "2018-08-01T21:30:17+05:30",
    },
    {
      eventId: "EVEN00003",
      eventType: "meeting",
      startDate: "2017-02-03T21:30:17+05:30",
    },
    {
      eventId: "EVEN00004",
      eventType: "email",
      startDate: "2018-09-04T21:30:17+05:30",
    },
    {
      eventId: "EVEN00005",
      eventType: "meeting",
      startDate: "2018-09-05T21:30:17+05:30",
    }
  ];
</script>
```